# Removing mean does not give symmetric signal

Tags: matlab, mean, symmetric

I am using 64-bit Windows with Matlab R2017a.

I have Matlab data stored in a vector [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q3cxouxj4773ccz/B.mat?dl=0). When I plot the data using the command `figure; plot(B)`, it looks like this:

[image]

Normally, when you remove the mean from a signal like this which looks almost periodic, the signal becomes symmetric about the x-axis. I tried this using the code `B2 = B - mean(B);`. Upon plotting with the command `figure; plot(B2)`, I get this:
[image]

which is not symmetric (max value is around 0.9 and min value is around -1.25). However, this result is not true for a very similar dataset found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jp33fxirwoeqpey/C.mat?dl=0). Before removing the mean, `C` looks like this:
[image]

And after, `C2 = C - mean(C)` looks like this:
[image]

which is symmetric about the x-axis (max value is around 1.1 and min value is around -1.1).

**What results in this difference for these two seemingly similar datasets?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Normally, when you remove the mean from a signal like this which looks almost periodic, the signal becomes symmetric about the x-axis."

That only is true, if your values are equally distributed. And your "looks periodic" is exactly what your dataset is: It looks kinda periodic, but it isn't. You have much more values close to zero than to -2. You see this a) when calculating your median, which is -0.1618 on dataset B and also visually the time it rests at zero is much longer (approx. 700 samples) than when it's around -2.2 (~400 samples).

Answer (score 1):

While Christians Answer is 100% correct. It doesn't offer a solution to the problem.
To center your function like you have it around the x-axis you would need to calculate:
B3 = B - (max(B) + min(B))/2

Note: This only works sol nicely because your function "look periodic"

Comment: :D

In my opinion the question was "What results in this difference for these two seemingly similar datasets?" and not a "Help me getting my plot into a range." But you're right, that could be also helpful :)